# Chrome claims Content Security Policy directive frame-src is not set, but it is

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, content-security-policy

as you can see in the screenshot, i would like to load a page via iFrame.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>XXXX</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src apexXXXX.XXXXXXXX.net">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="https://apexXXXX.XXXXXXXX.net/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

For me it's not possible to understand why Chrome refuses to do so.
Even when i use:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *">
```

the same error message appears. Of course i tried also several http-prefixes or trailing slashes. What am i doing wrong?

BR & Thanks!

John

(I spent hours to read similar posts, so there shouldn't be a duplicate)

Comment: Is "Content-Security-Policy: default-src *" set as a response header as well? It will have to pass both the meta element and all response header policies.

Comment: @John Steel: you published CSP `default-src 'self'` via HTTP header(in the server), therefore you can not relax it via meta tag. Either HTTP header or meta tag can be used, not both with different rules at the same time.

Comment: Thanks guys, there was a difference between the HTTP headers and the meta tags!

Answer (score 0):

Posting @granty's comment as answer as it is important.

> Either HTTP header or meta tag can be used, not both with different rules at the same time.

Meaning, if the HTTP server added the header, the meta tag won't override it